# Are one dyno, one app? In a Pipeline with two apps (stagging/production), I will have one or two dynos?

Tags: heroku

I'm thinking in use Heroku to some apps, but it's important to me to have the "Pipelines" working.

But, at this time, I can't understand if ONE pipeline with two apps (same codebase) will be counted as ONE dynos or TWO dynos.

One pipeline with two apps, is one dyno or two?

Answer (score 1):

For reference to someone with same question, Heroku Sales in response by email:

> "Each app in a pipeline is a separate app, and has separate dynos. If
>   you had a pipeline with two apps, you would have at minimum two
>   dynos."